# Inherited constructor, compiles in clang++3.9, fails in g++ 7

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, language-lawyer

This code snippet

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived: Base{
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() 
{
    Base b;
    Derived d{b};
}
```

[compiles fine on clang++3.9](https://godbolt.org/g/buX56c), however it [fails on all gcc's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1743be2631af6db) (including 7) and clangs with versions smaller than 3.9 with the error msg

> error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::Derived() Derived d{b}'.

**Is the code above standard compliant or not?**

PS: if I comment out the `using Base::Base` line, the code does not compile anymore on clang-3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [CWG 2356](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2356). It appears that both gcc and clang implement this already (clang 4.0+ rejects it), <s>despite it still being "tentatively ready" and not actually adopted into the working draft yet.</s> even thought it was only just adopted into the working draft in Rapperswil last month via [P1114](http://wiki.edg.com/pub/Wg21rapperswil2018/StrawPolls/p1114r0.html).

The rule there is that:

> A constructor inherited from class type `C` (15.6.3 [class.inhctor.init]) that has a first parameter of type “reference to *cv1* `P`” (including such a constructor instantiated from a template) is excluded from the set of candidate functions when constructing an object of type *cv2* `D` if the argument list has exactly one argument and `C` is reference-related to `P` and `P` is reference-related to `D`.

This excludes the `Base` copy constructor from consideration (in our case `C` and `P` are both `B`, and `B` is reference-related to `D`), which is why both compilers reject your code.

Comment: Thanks, to make sure I understand, the CWG 2356 proposal should make the code invalid, right? So I'll define an explicit copy ctor that invokes the base one.

Comment: 2356 was adopted at Rapperswil.